# Streaming compression to S3 bucket with a custom directory structure

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, compression

I have got an application that requires to create a compressed file from different objects that are saved on `S3`. The issue I am facing is I would like to compress objects on the fly without downloading files into a container and do the compression. The reason for that is the size of files can be quite big and I can easily run out of disk space and of course, there will be an extra round trip time of downloading files on disk, compressing them and upload the compressed file to `s3` again.

It is worth mentioning that I would like to locate files in the output compressed file in different directories, so when a user decompress the file can see it is stored in different folders.

Since `S3` does not have the concept of physical folder structure, I am not sure if this is possible and if there is a better way than download/uploading the files.

**NOTE**

My issue is not about how to use AWS Lambda to export a set of big files. It is about how I can export files from `S3` without downloading objects on a local disk and create a zip file and upload to `S3`. I would like to simply zip the files on `S3` on the fly and most importantly being able to customize the directory structure.

For example,

```
inputs:

big-file1
big-file2
big-file3
...

output:

big-zip.zip

with the directory structure of:

images/big-file1
images/big-file2
videos/big-file3
...
```

Answer (score 2):

I have almost the same use case as yours. I have researched it for about 2 months and try with multiple ways but finally I have to use ECS (EC2) for my use case because of the zip file can be huge like 100GB ....

1. Currently AWS doesn't support a native way to perform compress. I have talked to them and they are considering it a feature but there is no time line given yet.
2. If your files is about 3 GB in term of size, you can think of Lambda to achieve your requirement.
3. If your files is more than 4 GB, I believe it is safe to do it with ECS or EC2 and attach more volume if it requires more space/memory for compression.

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your help. We are using EKS actively, so this compression can be easily done in a statefull service. However, it's preferred to use streaming compression because the operational challenges and extra overhead of download, compress and upload to S3.

Comment: You are right. I doubt there are other options. Since S3 is for storing, not for computing (e.g. compressing). Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are at least two ways: either using AWS-Lambda or AWS-EC2

## EC2

Since [`aws-cli`](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli) [has support](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/903) of `cp` command, you can pipe `S3` file to any archiver using unix-pipe, e.g.:

`aws s3 cp s3://yours-bucket/huge_file - | gzip | aws s3 cp - s3://yours-bucket/compressed_file`

## AWS-Lambda

Since maintaining and using EC2 instance just for compressing may be too expensive, you can use Lambda for one-time compressions.

But keep in mind that Lambda has a lifetime limit of 15 minutes. So, if your files really huge try this sequence:

- To make sure that file will be compressed, try partial file compression using `Lambda`
- Compressed files could me merged on S3 into one file using [Upload Part - Copy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/mpUploadUploadPartCopy.html)

Comment: I my case there are multiple files I would like to compress in a single zip file and I want to customize the direction structure on the fly. Imagine coming with a directory for every month and store all the files related to that month inside it.

Comment: I actually had a closer look at aws-cli. It doesn't seem to be what I can use:

"This command would download the object stream from the bucket my-bucket and write it to stdout. Then the data in stdout will be piped to stdin and uploaded from stdin to an object with the key new-stream in the s3 bucket my-bucket"

I don't want to download files.